# Unhandled promise rejection warning and server connection error

Tags: mongodb, unix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBL3y.png)

Unhandled promise rejection warning and server connection error

Answer (score 1):

The unhandled promise rejection part is because you have a function that returns a promise that you don't `.catch()` and it threw an error.

It is probably in your `.connect()` call as it returns a promise that you don't catch.

As for your error, it seems like the version you use (of the driver) doesn't support the `useUnifiedTypology` option, so removing it might solve your issue.
It seems like this only works after version 3.2.1 of the driver as you can see in the changelog here:
[MongoDB v3.2.1 changelog](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/v3.2.1)